# Problem with cvCvtColor: unhandled exception at "0x1002e4e4" in "opencvsample.exe": 0xC0000005: Access read violation "0xffffffff"

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

I have a problem with OpenCV function cvCvtColor.
Here is the code I used:

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

int main(void)
{
 int  g_thresh = 100;
 CvCapture* capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0); 
    IplImage* g_image = cvQueryFrame(capture); 
 IplImage* g_image_copy = cvCloneImage(g_image);
 cvNamedWindow( "Contours", 1 );
 cvShowImage( "Contours", g_image );

 IplImage* g_gray = cvCreateImage( cvSize(g_image->width, g_image->height), g_image->depth, 1 );


 cvCvtColor( g_image_copy, g_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
 cvThreshold( g_gray, g_gray, g_thresh, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY );
 CvMemStorage*  g_storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
 CvSeq* contours = 0;

 cvFindContours( g_gray, g_storage, &contours );
 cvZero( g_gray );
 if( contours ){
  cvDrawContours(
   g_gray,
   contours,
   cvScalarAll(255),
   cvScalarAll(255),
   100 );
 }

 cvShowImage( "Contours", g_gray );
 cvWaitKey();

 return 0;
}
```

It's "unhandled exception at "0x1002e4e4" in "opencvsample.exe": 0xC0000005: Access read violation "0xffffffff"." (maybe I make mistakes in translation, I have russian VS2008).
It occurs at line

```
cvCvtColor( g_image_copy, g_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
```

What I need to do to solve problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a cvCvtColor() call in my application. Replacing the proposed libraries with their debug versions solved this issue for me.
I used:

```
cv200d.lib, cxcore200d.lib, highgui200d.lib
```

to link my application instead of

```
cv200.lib, cxcore200.lib, highgui200.lib
```

Btw: had the same issue after switching to OpenCV 2.1 - using the debug-versions again worked.